# Changing picture name by item.id in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this following function and I'm getting from a server API an item.id string value.

```
 renderItemList() {
return this.state.dataSource.map( item =>
    <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} style={[styles.imgbtn]}
                      onPress={() => {
                        Alert.alert("you voted for: " + item.id);
                      }}>
      <View style={styles.View}>
          <Image
              source={require('../ex1/images/flowers.png')}
          />

          <Text style={[styles.text]}>{String(item.id)}</Text>

      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

What I'm trying to do that instead of wr is to chain the picture name like this /ex1/images/*item.id*.png so I could show a different image for each key.id.

I would like to know how it's possible to do in react-native.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use string interpolation for this (Template Literals): `source={require(\`../ex1/images/${item.id}.png\`)}`?

Comment: Don't think so, tried what you wrote and it gave me error code 500

"The module `../ex1/images/${item.id}.png` could not be found from `C:\Users\OFIR_\WebstormProjects\shenkar\mobile\ex1\App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `${item.id}.png`"

Comment: Are you sure you're using backticks? Not single quotes.

Comment: I'm sure.
I've also copied your answer and it still gave me that same error.

Comment: Ah sorry, it looks like this doesn't get called at runtime for `require` statements. I'll have a quick look but for runtime based stuff, this just might not be possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the best information I was able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-native doesn't support dynamic requires, but there are ways you can achieve smiler behavior. I am attaching this example for reference.
https://snack.expo.io/rysnt5iUV

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: This doesn't seem possible at present, dynamic imports at runtime are simply not possible in React at this time.

Dyanamic imports are discussed here, and someone has mentioned that Webpack supports it:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391#issuecomment-383108403

As an alternative, you could use `eval`

`var path = '/path/' eval(const value=require('${path}')`

This might work as a nice alternative.

Comment: And in the code I wrote, how I should implement eval in there to show different pictures for each key.id? or I need to do a massive rework on my code.